# How does Julia's @spawnat initialize variables on remote worker process?

Tags: parallel-processing, scope, julia, remote-server

Below is some output; I can't completely understand what is going on here. Specifically, where are variables d,e,f after they are initialized? Are they created and destroyed dynamically on worker 2?

```
julia> addprocs(1)
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 2

julia> whos()
Base                          Module
Core                          Module
Main                          Module
ans                           1-element Array{Any,1}

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 whos())
        From worker 2:  Base                          Module
        From worker 2:  Core                          Module
        From worker 2:  Main                          Module

julia> a,b,c= 10,20,30
(10,20,30)

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 a,b,c = (50,60,70))
(50,60,70)

julia> a,b,c
(10,20,30)

julia> whos()
Base                          Module
Core                          Module
Main                          Module
a                             Int64
ans                           (Int64,Int64,Int64)
b                             Int64
c                             Int64

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 whos())
        From worker 2:  Base                          Module
        From worker 2:  Core                          Module
        From worker 2:  Main                          Module

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 d,e,f = (a,b,c))
(10,20,30)

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 whos())
        From worker 2:  Base                          Module
        From worker 2:  Core                          Module
        From worker 2:  Main                          Module

julia> whos()
Base                          Module
Core                          Module
Main                          Module
a                             Int64
ans                           Nothing
b                             Int64
c                             Int64

julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 0.3.5
Commit a05f87b* (2015-01-08 22:33 UTC)
Platform Info:
System: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz
WORD_SIZE: 64
BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Nehalem)
LAPACK: libopenblas
LIBM: libopenlibm
LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

My real problem is about data movement when function is invoked on remote worker via @spawnat, i.e. my understanding is that

```
> @spawnat 2 func(a,b,c)
```

would cause a,b & c to be moved from local to remote. If a & c existed in the scope of remote, would the movement still happen? a & c in my case are large arrays and I have preloaded them on all workers. b is calculated on local before invoking @spawnat 2 func(a,b,c).

Can this be done with @spawnat? Any other workaround?

Comment: I'm not sure that your premise is correct.  `a,b,c = 10,20,30` on the local process only defines it there, not on the other worker procs.  You can see this with `fetch(@spawnat 2 whos())` or `fetch(@spawnat 2 eval(:(a,b,c)))`.    `fetch(@spawnat 2 a,b,c)` also does not define the variables on the remote proc.  If you do define `a, b, c` on the remote procs with something like `@everywhere a,b,c = 10,20,30`, then you can retrieve/use them with something like `fetch(@spawnat 2 eval(:(a,b,c)))` or `fetch(@spawnat 2 eval(:(func(a,b,c))))`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks, my understanding is incomplete. Based on your feedback, I have edited the question and appended some more output.

Comment: Might be easiest to write a "helper" function that only takes `b` as a parameter that then calls your original function that uses `a, b, c`.  You might also consider using `remotecall_fetch` or even `pmap` (with a suitable collection) if you have an embarrassingly parallel problem.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: Wrote a helper function and managed to use pmap() as well; really good suggestions! Thanks.